# Java servlet download the file using href

Tags: java, html, servlets

Servlet page i have to create a table and inside the table creating a href tag to download the file from the desired location

Below is my Servlet code

```
 String fileName = resultSet.getString("attachmentfilename");
 out.println("<TR><TD>" + "Attachment Name" + "</TD>"
 + "<TD><a href=\\\\xxx.xx.xx.xx\\DOC\\\\"+fileName+" download ="+fileName+">Click to download</a></TD></TR>");
```

while Clicking the "Click to download" hyperlink there is no response, let me know the problem

Answer (score 0):

This code above is to view the link, here you have to write a code to handle the download file separately and write it in the response like a servlet to handle the request and configure it to receive a file name and then you know how to get the file and send it back with the response.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to download any file using ahref

```
<a href="full_path_to_file/XYZ.jpg" download> click to download </a>
```